# I can not make a formcontact working

Tags: contacts

I am a beginner , i try to make my website and i encountered a problem with my contacting form. What i want to know if i make something wrong with what i doing or is a problem from my host.

I have this form:

```
    <div id="frmdiv_cform">

<script src="../code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js" tppabs="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
     $("#contactForm").submit(function(event) 
     {
         /* stop form from submitting normally */
         event.preventDefault();

         /* get some values from elements on the page: */
         var $form = $( this ),
             $submit = $form.find( 'button[type="submit"]' ),
             name_value = $form.find( 'input[name="name"]' ).val(),
             email_value = $form.find( 'input[name="email"]' ).val(),
             message_value = $form.find( 'textarea[name="message"]' ).val(),


car1_value = $form.find( 'input[name="car1"]' ).val(),
car2_value = $form.find( 'input[name="car2"]' ).val(),
whereused_value = $form.find( 'input[name="whereused"]' ).val(),
phone_value = $form.find( 'input[name="phone"]' ).val(),
whenrequired_value = $form.find( 'input[name="whenrequired"]' ).val(),

             url = $form.attr('action');

         /* Send the data using post */
         var posting = $.post( url, { 
                           name: name_value, 
                           email: email_value, 
                           message: message_value,
               car1: car1_value,
               car2: car2_value,
               whereused: whereused_value,
               phone: phone_value,
               whenrequired: whenrequired_value
                       });

         posting.done(function( data )
         {
             /* Put the results in a div */
             $( "#contactResponse" ).html(data);

             /* Change the button text. */
             $submit.text('Sent, Thank you');

             /* Disable the button. */
             $submit.attr("disabled", true);
         });
    });
</script>



<form id="contactForm" method="POST" action="contact.php" >


                        <fieldset id="frmWrap_cform">
                            <div class="control-group">



                                <label class="control-label" for="car1">Vehicle</label>
                                <input id="car1" class="formcontrol formcontrol95" type="text" maxlength="250" placeholder="Required" required="" value=''>
                            </div>
                            <input id="car2" class="formcontrol formcontrol95" type="text" maxlength="250" placeholder="(optional)">
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label" for="whereused">Garage</label>
                                <input id="whereused" class="formcontrol formcontrol95" type="text" maxlength="50" placeholder="Required" required="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label" for="custname">Your name</label>
                                <input id="name" class="formcontrol formcontrol95" type="text" maxlength="50" placeholder="Required" required="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="control-group">
                                    "custphone">Your phone number</label>
                                <input id="phone" class="formcontrol formcontrol95" type="text" maxlength="50" placeholder="Required" required="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label" for="custemail">Your email</label>
                                <input id="email" class="formcontrol formcontrol95" type="text" maxlength="250" placeholder="Required" required="">
                            </div>
                            <label>When is required?</label>
                            <input id="whenrequired" class="formcontrol formcontrol95" type="text" maxlength="250">
                            <label>Comments / exact requirements:</label>
                            <textarea id='message' rows='3' class='formcontrol formcontrol95' placeholder='e.g. specific options/engine/transmission you require, delivery required etc'></textarea>
                            <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="addtomailing"> Please tick here</label>
                            <hr style="margin:2px 0 7px 0;">
                            <button id="comments_cform" data-item-id="-999" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-submit-version-form">Send enquiry</button>
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
```

I look on the internet and i try many solution.
What should i have it contact.php?
All the things that i try its nit working.

Only this code send me a blank email .

```
<?php

$car1    = $_POST['car1'];
$car2    = $_POST['car2'];
$companyname    = $_POST['companyname'];
$name    = $_POST['name'];
$phone    = $_POST['name'];
$email    = $_POST['name'];
$country = $_POST['name'];
$zipcode = $_POST['name'];
$street = $_POST['name'];   
$message = $_POST['name'];

$to      = "XXX@XXX.com";
$subject = "Mailer";
$message = "";
$headers = "From: $email";

if( mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers) )
{
    echo "<h2>Thank you for your comment</h2>";
}
else
{
    echo "<h2>Sorry, there has been an error</h2>";
}
```

?>

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please help me , it make me crazy. Let me know if i need something else . Anyone?

Comment: can anyone help me? even without the correct solution.